# NSMutableArray insertObject atIndex issues

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsmutablearray

There are lots of examples on this site about adding to NSMutableArray and I have looked at many but I still don't either understand (highly possible) or am missing something fundamental.

I am trying to add to an NSMutableArray via a for loop. I want to keep track of button x,y coordinate position using the button tag as key/index so I can change a button as a user clicks it. This is all without IB.

My init is as follow:

> > self.tmpXpos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> >     self.tmpYpos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> >
> > [self.tmpXpos insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:0];
> >
> > [self.tmpYpos insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:0];
> >     **I added these after reading about 'creating' the array and populating it with null.

In the loop:

> > NSUInteger btag = button.tag;  //NSUInterger as per help

```
>>NSNumber *xNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self xpos]]; // NSNumber as an Object wrapper
>>NSNumber *yNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self ypos]];


>>[self.tmpXpos insertObject:xNumber atIndex:btag];
>>[self.tmpYpos insertObject:yNumber atIndex:btag];
```

> > NSLog(@"%d, %@, %@",btag,xNumber,yNumber);

The log entries look ok:

2,64,0

3,128,0

etc for each button to be added to the screen.

During debugging - the tmpXpos and tmpYpos listed as " 0 Objects " under self.

I retrieve the information thusly:

> > NSUInteger tmpSt = [self.sTags integerValue];
> >
> > NSNumber *tmpX = [self.tmpXpos objectAtIndex:tmpSt];
> >
> > NSNumber *tmpY = [self.tmpYpos objectAtIndex:tmpSt];
> >
> > int tmpPositionX = [tmpX intValue];
> >
> > int tmpPositionY = [tmpY intValue];
> >
> > NSLog(@"%d, %d",tmpPositionX, tmpPositionY);

NSLog yields 0, 0

I do appreciate any guidance or questions you folks might have as this site's 'sanity checks' have saved my bacon in the past.

I am ignoring memory leaks as of yet, but they are in the back of my mind.  No worries there.
Ironically, I have a couple of other arrays that work just fine, but the exception is that they are not populated via a loop.

Lastly, the code works fine as the button at location 0,0 does change as per design, LOL, but not for any other location.

Thanks again!

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are creating the NSNumbers with the method numberWithInteger, when an NSUInteger is actually an unsigned long. So try

xNumber = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:[self xpos]];

Comment: Great idea, but it didn't work.  The content of the object self.xpos is just an integer as well, which gave me the idea to try 'numberWithInteger'  However the ' numberWithUnsignedLong ' didn't change the array content: 0 Objects via self in debug.

Comment: THis is giving me fits, so I think I am going to punt and hard code the coordinates from the log file!

Comment: Oh, wait i just looked at the way you retrieve the information, and you cast an integer into an unsigned long. NSUInteger tmpSt = [self.sTags integerValue];

Comment: Also, when you say your init method, do you mean that that code is in your classes actual init method, because if so that method won't be called unless you allocate an instance of that class elsewhere.

Comment: @user397313 - exactly right, and I did do that under -loadView.  My other arrays are instantiated by this method and work fine. I just have to find a way to populate an array without using a loop.. any ideas?

Comment: This is weird, i've used loops lots of times to do stuff similar to this, and never had this sort of problem. Right now with what I know about your code, i'm not really sure what to do, if you want you can send me your .h and .m files and i'll look at them and email you back, my email is jchancehud@gmail.com .

Comment: @User397313 - I created a smaller test project to validate my code, thinking something must be amok!  But the problem persists. I will send you the code.. the test project is really small.

Comment: Sorry about that @user397313 - in the test code, I forgot to initializes the arrays.  Having done so, the code now works for the test.   

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Trees for the forest answer.  I wanted to populate an array with a quantity, however, the array expects that quantity to be in numerical sequence.  My data didn't have any 'gaps' but wasn't in sequence either; I.E., 1,2,3,6,7,12 etc. So, as user397313 helped me see, NSDictionary is the way to go with that kind of datum.